# Filtering out (blank) within a PivotFiled from all pivottables in a workbook that have the same pivotfields

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba, pivot-table

I have a bunch (14) of pivottables in two worksheets (7 in each worksheet).

I have a refresh button on the sheet that refreshes all pivottables using the following code:

```
Sub Refresh_Pivots()

Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each pt In WS.PivotTables
          pt.RefreshTable
          Next pt
    Next WS
End Sub
```

All the pivottables have similar structure and there is one filed called "Month" in all pivottables. I need to filter out "(blank)" from the PivotField "Month" in all PivotTables when I click Refresh.

For that I added this one line under the Nested For Loop after pt.RefreshTable -

```
pt.pf("month").pi("(blank)").ShowDetail = False
```

So the changed code is:

Sub Refresh_Pivots()

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pi As PivotItem
Dim WS As Worksheet
    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each pt In WS.PivotTables
          pt.RefreshTable
          pt.pf("month").pi("(blank)").ShowDetail = False
          Next pt
    Next WS
End Sub
```

But, I'm getting a compilation error. I cannot figure out why. I'm relatively new to VBA so I'm sorry if this is a silly question.

Also, I need those blanks in the data, just need to filter them out from the PivotTables. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to replace pf with PivotFields and pi with PivotItems